# responsive indicator line with tab and content

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, animation

can anyone help me creating an animation, click any tab, the indicator line should move to the active tab(one side to the active tab, other side to the content which is static).  I tried by reducing the width of the indicator line image but it also compresses from the other side too. is there another way of doing this? any help would be appreciated.  see attached image.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAL49.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that:

```js
function select(nb) {
  $("a").removeClass('underline');
  $("#" + nb).addClass('underline')
}
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="1" onclick="select('1')">1</a>
<a id="2" onclick="select('2')">2</a>
<a id="3" onclick="select('3')">3</a>
<a id="4" onclick="select('4')">4</a>
```

Comment: better use `this.id`, like `onclick="select(this.id)"`